How to crop an xarray Dataset using a Shapefile with non-standard grid coordinates
I have a netCDF dataset with dimensions represented by 'xc' and 'yc', which are in meters, and the CRS of the dataset is Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection with the following parameters:
Grid Mapping Name: Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area
Longitude of Projection Origin: 0.0
Latitude of Projection Origin: -90.0
False Easting: 0.0
False Northing: 0.0
Semi-major Axis: 6378137.0
Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563
Proj4 String: +proj=laea +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=-90.0

I also have a shapefile that represents the area I want to crop from the dataset.
I'm trying to crop this dataset using the shapefile, but I'm facing some difficulties due to the non-standard grid coordinates and CRS.
Here's what I've tried so far:
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray
import xarray as xr

# Open the netCDF dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset("./sea ice_2021_07.nc")
print(ds)

Here is the output :
> <xarray.Dataset> Dimensions:   (xc: 432, yc: 432) Coordinates:   * xc 
> (xc) float64 -5.388e+03 -5.362e+03 ... 5.362e+03 5.388e+03   * yc     
> (yc) float64 5.388e+03 5.362e+03 ... -5.362e+03 -5.388e+03
>     time      datetime64[ns] ...
>     lat       (yc, xc) float32 ...
>     lon       (yc, xc) float32 ... Data variables:
>     ice_conc  (yc, xc) float64 ...

shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file('polygon.shp').geometry.to_list()
print(gdf)

Shapefile output in usual lat long format:
[<POLYGON ((-180 -64.4, -180 -64.4, -180 -64.5, -180 -64.5, -180 -64.6, -180 ...>]

The problem occurred when running the code rio.clip. It shows only one lat (should be more) and the cropped image is entirely null/empty.
ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
clipped = ds.rio.clip(gdf, crs="epsg:4326")
print(clipped)

The output looks like :
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                 (xc: 13, yc: 1)
Coordinates:
  * xc                      (xc) float64 -137.5 -112.5 -87.5 ... 137.5 162.5
  * yc                      (yc) float64 -62.5
    time                    datetime64[ns] ...
    lat                     (yc, xc) float32 ...
    lon                     (yc, xc) float32 ...
    Lambert_Azimuthal_Grid  int64 0
Data variables:
    ice_conc                (yc, xc) float64 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan

Why this is happening? I think, there is a problem in non-standard grid coordinates.
Could someone guide me on how to properly crop the dataset using the shapefile, taking into account the non-standard grid coordinates and CRS?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Dataset and shapefile are here drive

Can you clarify what you mean by "crop"? You have a gridded dataset. Typically cropping of netCDF results in a rectangular box, but that's not what you want. Do you want everything outside the shapefile to become nan?

Thanks @RobertWilson for your kind reply. Actually I want to do the clipping of my neCDF based on the shapefile. I want to remove the data outside of the shapefile. Only the shapefile will have the data.

@Rony Golder, I think there is a conflict between your .nc file and the shapefile as they are in different coordinate systems (the shapefile doesn't seem projected). So, need to fix that. After that, there are some good suggestions here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353698/how-to-clip-an-xarray-to-a-smaller-extent-given-the-lat-lon-coordinates
